# Prolog. Вычисление числа вхождения 1го элемента на основе стандартных предикатов обработки списков

Tags: список, prolog

Собственно вот код, к которому нужно это реализовать:

```
%
%    Задание 3.
%

% Длина списка %
length_new([], 0).

length_new([_ | A], B):-
    length_new(A, C),
    B is C + 1.

% Принадлежность к списку %
member_new(A, [A | _]).

member_new(A, [_ | B]):-
    member_new(A, B).

% Конкатинация списков %
append_new([], A, A).

append_new([A | X1], X2, [A | X3]):-
    append_new(X1, X2, X3).

% Удаление элемента из списка
remove_new(St, [St | End], End).

remove_new(St, [A | End], [A | Ne]):-
    remove_new(St, End, Ne).


% Перестановка элементов списка %
permute_new([], []).

permute_new(A, [St | En]):-
    remove_new(St, A, N),
    permute_new(N, En).

%  Является ли список Sub подсписком списка List. %
sublist_new(Sub, List):-
    append_new(_, NewList, List), 
    append_new(Sub, _, NewList).

%
%    Задание 4. Удаление трех последних элементов
%

% Используя стандартные предикаты
removethree(In, Out) :-  
    append([_,_,_], Out, In).


% Используя свои предикаты
removethree_new(In, Out) :-  
     append_new([_,_,_], Out, In).

%
%    Задание 5. Вычисление числа вхождения 1-го элемента
%

% Используя стандартные предикаты
```

Вот код аналогичной функции, использующей свои предикаты:

```
count(_, [], 0).
count(X, [X|T], N) :-
    !
    count(X, T, NN),
    N is NN + 1.
count(X, [_|T], N) :-
    count(X, T, N).

count_first(L, N) :-
    L = [H|_],
    count(H, L, N).
```

ЯП: SWI-Prolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compose([X|_], X).

count(List, Count):
  compose(List, Element), %Указание первого элемента
  findall(Element, member(Element, List), Counters), % Поиск одинаковых элементов и добавление их в список
  length(Counters, Count). % Длина списка
```

Comment: добавь описание что именно происходит в данном блоке кода

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: а как этот код относится в коду в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy не понял вопроса...
Код в примере нужен для понимания структуры, и что требуется сделать.
Также я дал пример функции, построенной на своих предикатах (без использования стандартных)

Comment: Пока ты не дал своего ответа было непонятно что именно ты хотел. Больше походило, что надо было сделать по аналогии с тем, что уже в вопросе, возможно даже и использованием функций из вопроса